# How to activate an element by triggering a click event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an div element and set a default color. When it is active the color changes. So, when clicking using a mouse the color will change to red. I'm also triggering a click event when the DOM is ready. But, when I trigger the click event the behavior is not the same. The element does not change color and it disappears. What is the best way to achieve it?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvcwxLjr/.

```
var ele = document.querySelector('.clickMe');
ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('You\'ve clicked me');
});
ele.click();
```

I know it can be done by creating another class that has background red and add that when mouse down and remove when mouse up. Is there a better way?

Comment: So essentially you're asking why isn't the CSS `active` state trigger programmatically from the click event?

Comment: You need to add the class 'active' to the element in your event handler and change your css so that:

.clickMe:active {
  background-color: green;
}

is:

.clickMe.active{
  background: green;
}

The css selector with the colon is not correct.

Comment: DIVs can't be active. That only applies to certain types of elements, such as anchors and buttons.

Comment: @j08691 Yes. That is exactly what I want to understand.

Comment: @Barmar If that is the case, why don't you click the div. You will see a change in color.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The problem is that it's only active while the mouse button is held down. When you trigger the click event, it's not the same as holding the mouse down, because it lets go immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
$(".clickMe").click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  alert('change green');
  });
 });
```

```css
   .clickMe {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickMe">
 </div>
```

Comment: It is going to stay green after you click. That is not the objective.

Comment: so you want to back it on red ??

Comment: Yes. But you can do it by listening to mouse down and mouse up events. That is not the point. The point is why is the behavior different when triggering a click programmatically versus actually clicking using your mouse?

Comment: your code is also working . with hold mouse down you can see the green color. but remove the  last line ele.click(); because of that your code run with click or put it inside the the closing tag also give you two time click event. so better remove that line.. and mine was working coz I remove the active class and set a css for the.. You can get your color red back with settimeout function.

Comment: The goal is to make it work by programmatically triggering the click event.

Answer (score 0):

'alert' function will block ui thread in browser([more info](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8420902)), in other words, `alert` blocked the div to be rendered with red color. Alternatively, you can use `console.log`, like this :

```
var ele = document.querySelector('.clickMe');
ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
 console.log('You\'ve clicked me');
});
ele.click();
```

Comment: I agree. But, go to the element and click. Not the same behavior. What we are discussing is manually clicking versus click triggered by Javascript. Why are they different?